# is there a way to dynamically change the number of answers in a quiz question embedded in a learnr tutorial?

Tags: r-markdown, learnr

I am interested in feeding a varying number of answers taken as arguments for a `learnr` quiz question.

Like, for instance, building the 'body' of a `question_checkbox`
from external lists of questions and answers (like taken from a csv).

In the example provided in the `learnr` tutorial, the question is built manually. I want to understand how to do it dynamically.

```
question_checkbox(
  "Select all the toppings that belong on a Margherita Pizza:",
  answer("mozzarella", correct = TRUE),
  answer("basil", correct = TRUE),
  answer("onions"),
  answer("spinach"),
  random_answer_order = TRUE,
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  try_again = "Be sure to select all toppings!"
)
```

I tried feeding the answers as a list, which is prevented by the answer's specific class (`"tutorial_question_answers" "tutorial quiz answer"`).

I tried a workaround using r/exams which appears to allow embedding `r/exams` quiz files and uses the `exams2learnr` function to convert them to`learnr` exercises, but for some reason it does not work.

The only question on StackOverflow that is relatively close is [Is there a way to import questions and answers from a spreadsheet into a learnr quiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921246/is-there-a-way-to-import-questions-and-answers-from-a-spreadsheet-into-a-learnr) but it is about dynamically extracting data from external sources and using them as (a fixed number of) arguments, *not* about *dynamically changing the number of arguments* itself (e.g., the number of possible answers). It takes me half there but not all the way (I'll keep trying to modify it myself in the meantime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `do.call`.

Not sure about the structure of your input data. Hence, based on the example from the docs I first created two datasets, one containing the data on the questions, one containing the answers. As a first step I join the two datasets where I put the answers data in a list column (via `tidyr::nest`).

After this preliminary steps I use `purrr::pmap` to loop over the questions (even if the example contains only one). For each question I use a second `pmap` step to dynamically create the list of `answer()`s which are then be passed to `question_checkbox` via `do.call`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
date: "2023-10-18"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(learnr)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
questions <- tibble::tibble(
  qid = "q01",
  text = "Select all the toppings that belong on a Margherita Pizza:",
  random_answer_order = TRUE,
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  try_again = "Be sure to select all four toppings!"
)

answers <- tibble::tibble(
  qid = "q01",
  text = c(
    "tomato", "mozzarella", "basil",
    "pepperoni", "extra virgin olive oil",
    "onions", "bacon", "spinach"
  ),
  correct = c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 4)),
  message = c(
    rep(NA, 3),
    "Great topping! ... just not on a Margherita Pizza",
    rep(NA, 4)
  )
)

answers <- answers |>
  tidyr::nest(answers = -qid)

questions_answers <- questions |>
  left_join(answers, by = "qid")
```

```{r}
glimpse(questions_answers)
```

```{r create-questions, include=FALSE}
create_answers <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  args$message <- if (!is.na(args$message)) args$message
  do.call(learnr::answer, args)
}

q_checkbox <- purrr::pmap(
  questions_answers,
  function(...) {
    args <- list(...)
    args$qid <- NULL
    answers <- purrr::pmap(args$answers, create_answers)
    do.call(
      learnr::question_checkbox,
      c(args[!names(args) == "answers"], answers)
    )
  }
)
```

```{r q01}
q_checkbox[[1]]
```
````

[image]

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan), this was beautiful :) I went through your answer a couple of times and it still amazes me. And so quickly...  I can take it from here. My apologies for not being clear about the data structure, but you nailed that too.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW: No need to add a link to my profile if you want to ping me. Just use @stefan. And if you add a comment on one of my answers even that is not necessary. (: